# Search string with dynamic value in Splunk

Tags: splunk

I have data in `splunk` like this:

```
DEBUG demp.find - [Local-Log] Parameters name/city/isActive/: 3/XYZ/true/false
DEBUG demp.find - [Local-Log] Parameters name/city/isActive/: 4/AHJGS/true/false
DEBUG demp.find - [Local-Log] Parameters name/city/isActive/: 3/AJJ/true/false
DEBUG demp.find - [Local-Log] Parameters name/city/isActive/: 6/XYZ/true/false
DEBUG demp.find - [Local-Log] Parameters name/city/isActive/: 3/XYZ/true/false
DEBUG demp.find - [Local-Log] Parameters name/city/isActive/: 6/123/true/false
DEBUG demp.find - [Local-Log] Parameters name/city/isActive/: 3/HJG/true/false
```

I want to get the this result from a `splunk` query where `name` value is dynamic, I dont care about anything after that

like: `Parameters name/city/isActive/: {regex here to get name value}` and save that in new values to user further. Kindly guide me for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rex field=_raw "Parameters name/city/isActive/:(?<all>(?<part1>.*)/(?<part2>.*)/(?<part3>.*)/(?<part4>.*))"
```